# How to integrate Google Analytics in Titanium iphone app

Tags: iphone, google-analytics, titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy

How to integrate google Analytics in titanium iphone app.
I tried google analytics using following link.

https://github.com/rogchap/Titanium-Google-Analytics/blob/master/Resources/app.js

But its not working for me. I unable to find issue.

**NOTE : I am working with Alloy.**

Please suggest.

Comment: did you install the required module? please provide some sample code of YOUR app...

Comment: I tried exactly from https://github.com/rogchap/Titanium-Google-Analytics/blob/master/Resources/app.js link. I know this link is not following Alloy. But i tried without using alloy(Titanium iphone development). But i don't get any positive result from this link

Comment: yeah but `var gaModule = require('Ti.Google.Analytics');` implies that you downloaded and installed the Google Analytics Module. Did you do that?

Comment: yes i did and i use Ti.API.log('this function working.'); like wise inside each google analytics function.. All Google analytics functions are working well, but this not making any changes in Google Analytics Account.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you will have to wait for an update if you set your app up as mobile in google analytics according to the issue below.  It appears we will need to setup our titanium apss up as websites in GA for now:

https://github.com/rogchap/Titanium-Google-Analytics/issues/11

Comment: This version has been deprecated since it only supports Google Analytics v1